# firebase data using user.getUid

Tags: android

hi guys how can i send a data to **firebase** when i logging in want to see different info from other accounts now i see the save data that i sent. this is a code:

This is my Activity_category Activity

```
public class Activity_category  extends Activity {

    class Layout{

        Layout(){

            textView2= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            listview1=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);
            registerForContextMenu(listview1);


        }
        TextView textView2;
        RecyclerView listview1;

    }


    class Events{

        Events(){

            firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User_Details");
            l.listview1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Activity_category.this));
            Toast.makeText(Activity_category.this, "Wait !  Fetching List...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



          //  l.listview1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
               // @Override
               // public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long id) {

               // }
          //  });




        }

    }

    Layout l;
    Events e;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference myRef;
     FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<showdataitems, ShowDataViewHolder> mFirebaseAdapter;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview);
        l = new Layout(); e = new Events();
    }
    public Activity_category() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }



    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //Log.d("LOGGED", "IN onStart ");
        mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<showdataitems, ShowDataViewHolder>(showdataitems.class, R.layout.category, ShowDataViewHolder.class, myRef) {




            public void populateViewHolder(final ShowDataViewHolder viewHolder, showdataitems model, final int position) {
                viewHolder.Image_URL(model.getImage_URL());
                viewHolder.Image_Title(model.getImage_Title());


                //OnClick Item
                viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final View v) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity_category.this);
                        builder.setMessage("Do you want to Delete this data ?").setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        int selectedItems = position;
                                        mFirebaseAdapter.getRef(selectedItems).removeValue();
                                        mFirebaseAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(selectedItems);
                                        l.listview1.invalidate();
                                        onStart();
                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.setTitle("Confirm");
                        dialog.show();
                    }
                });


            }
        };


        l.listview1.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter);
    }


    //View Holder For Recycler View
    public static class ShowDataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final TextView text1;
        private final ImageView imageView3;



        public ShowDataViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView3 = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            text1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);


        }

        private void Image_Title(String title) {
            text1.setText(title);
        }

        private void Image_URL(String title) {
            // image_url.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading);
            Glide.with(itemView.getContext())
                    .load(title)
                    .crossFade()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.newmenu1)
                    .thumbnail(0.1f)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(imageView3);
        }



    }












    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();


        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case 1:


                break;

        }


        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
```

This is my Uploadinfo Activity

```
public class Uploadinfo  extends Activity{

    class Layout{

        Layout(){

            menuBtn= (Button)findViewById(R.id.menuBtn);
            cancelBtn= (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);
            btnAddimage= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddimage);
            imageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            editText= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);



        }
        Button menuBtn , cancelBtn,btnAddimage;
        ImageView imageView;
        EditText editText;

    }


    class Events{

        Events(){


            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Uploadinfo.this);
            l.btnAddimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)  {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Call for Permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                        {
                            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        callgalary();
                    }
                }
            });


            mdatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            mRoofRef = new Firebase("https://restaurant-menu-4bdf2.firebaseio.com/").child("User_Details").push();  // Push will create new child every time we upload data
            mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("gs://restaurant-menu-4bdf2.appspot.com/");

            l.menuBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    final String mName = l.editText.getText().toString().trim();


                    if(mName.isEmpty())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fill all Field", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    Firebase childRef_name = mRoofRef.child("Image_Title");
                    childRef_name.setValue(mName);


                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updated Info", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            });







        }

    }

    Layout l;
    Events e;
    public static final int READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 0;
    private static final int GALLERY_INTENT = 2;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private Firebase mRoofRef;
    private Uri mImageUri = null;
    private DatabaseReference mdatabaseRef;
    private StorageReference mStorage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        l = new Layout(); e = new Events();
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    callgalary();
                return;
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    private void callgalary() {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent();
        intent1.setType("image/*");
        intent1.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent1, "Select Picture"), GALLERY_INTENT);
    }


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            mImageUri = data.getData();
            l.imageView.setImageURI(mImageUri);
            StorageReference filePath = mStorage.child("User_Images").child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Uploading Image....");
            mProgressDialog.show();

            filePath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();  //Ignore This error

                    mRoofRef.child("Image_URL").setValue(downloadUri.toString());

                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                            .load(downloadUri)
                            .crossFade()
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.newmenu1)
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
                            .into( l.imageView);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updated.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```